# Add pdf files to robots.txt on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have several PDF files uploaded on Wordpress (via Media Uploader), that should not be indexed by Google. The only solution I could find was to add the filenames on my `robots.txt`, denying robots to crawl these files.

The problem is that this method requires a constant update of my `robots.txt` file. Which is not a good solution if more people start working on this project (on this case, Editors). They probably will not be able to update the `robots.txt` file.

Is there any way to dinamically add a PDF file on my robots.txt? Maybe a custom field where if it is true, then the file is added?

An important detail: some of the PDFs uploaded via Media Uploader should be indexed. But some should not. That is why I can't add a rule that filter all PDF files.

Comment: Do you want some PDF crawled?  Do you store them in a directory you could exclude?

Comment: The file is just like any other hosted file.  You could write a script or something to edit the file, but that seems complicated and probably not worth it.  Maybe storing the PDF in such a way that it can be excluded by a rule?  Either in a separate directory or by naming convention?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt), you can exclude by directory or file type or both.  So long as you don't want any to be crawled, you could use `Disallow: /*.pdf`